# Login failed for user 'domain\ServerName'

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication, sql-authentication

I have creates an asp.net mvc 4 web app. I have deployed it to my dev server. (different box than my local on same domain).

Both the database and the website exists on the same server/box. I am trying to connect from my local machine which is on the same domain as the server.

I try to login on the home page and I get this error:
Login failed for user 'domain\ServerName'

I don't know where this is coming from or how to resolve it. I assume it has something to do with IIS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the server on the same domain as your computer? What browser are you using? If not internet explorer / not on the same subnet, have you enabled NTLM/Kerberos support?

Comment: Yes same domain. Chrome. How do you enable NTLM/Kerberos support?

Comment: In firefox, you need to set [network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris](http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/). I can't remember for Chrome but I believe it's based off the internet zone for the site (as defined by the Internet Options in control panel used by IE)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem - It was my connection string.  Somehow, it now magically now had both `;User ID={login value here};Password={password value here}` and `Trusted_Connection=True;` key/value pairs.

You cannot use both.  If you have a SQL Server login, then you don't want the `Trusted_Connection=True;`. If you have a trust between machines, then you don't want the `;User ID={login value here};Password={password value here}` values.

It makes sense that this applies to `Integrated Security=SSPI;` and `Integrated Security=true;` too. You must leave off `User ID` and `password` when you use those as well.

*(6 years late, but maybe it'll help someone else)*